# How to get all full CREATE TABLE statements from a mysql dump

Tags: mysql, regex, awk, sed

I got this so far:

```
$ bzcat mysqldump.pplware.sql.bz2 | grep -A 10 "^CREATE TABLE.*"
CREATE TABLE `wp_ak_twitter` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tw_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `tw_text` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `tw_reply_username` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tw_reply_tweet` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tw_created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `modified` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `tw_id` (`tw_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
--
CREATE TABLE `wp_audit_trail` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `operation` varchar(40) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ip` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `happened_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `item_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `data` longtext,
  `title` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9442523 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

..and so on.
But the 10 line limit is arbitrary, and some of the CREATE TABLES are shorter and some are longer. How can I get all full CREATE TABLE definitions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select lines between two patterns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38972736/how-to-select-lines-between-two-patterns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about printing lines between patterns: `CREATE TABLE` and `;` semi-colon:-

```
bzcat mysqldump.pplware.sql.bz2 | awk '/CREATE TABLE/{f=1}/\;/{f=0}f||/\;/'
```

OR

```
bzcat mysqldump.pplware.sql.bz2 | awk '/CREATE TABLE/,/\;/'
```

Answer (score 0):

How about just getting the definitions, without the data:

```
mysqldump ... --no-data ...
```

(Sure, this does not answer the question *as asked*, but it *may* provide an easy solution in some cases.)